# beefy command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, git-bash

I am new to node.js and trying to follow this [tutorial](http://learnjs.io/blog/2014/03/04/gameloop-load-images-sprite-2d/). I am getting an error on the last command `beefy game.js:bundle.js --live`. It says `sh.exe": beefy: command not found`

The [beefy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/beefy) package version I am using is 2.1.1

[image: sh.exe": beefy: command not found]

Tried to Google this problem but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not followed the tutorial in detail, but the response form the console means that the the console command or program called beefy is not installed.  The first word of your input into the console will be interpreted to be a command (a little program) that will run.

For instance `cd` is a program to change directory and the next thing you enter will specify a directory to which to change.

`beefy` is not a command/console program that is in your system.  (It is not a standard command.) Probably somewhere else in the tutorial you were instructed to install it in one of your various bin/ directories (where shell program commands are stored.)

EDIT:

**TL;DR**
The fix: install beefy globally (on your machine not for directory only) using npm:

```
npm install beefy --global
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have installed node.js following this [tutorial](http://learnjs.io/blog/2014/01/22/js-development-environment/). And also this doesn't seem to be a common problem as didn't find any related question on google.

Comment: beefy does not come with node.  You need to install it manually, which you can do using the package manager that comes with node called npm.

Comment: This can be done with the following command in the shell: `npm install beefy --global`

Comment: Thanx @Ralph, the command `npm install beefy --global` worked like a charm.